# Selenium with Chrome and Safari insane speed difference leads to problems

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm not experienced nor a beginner programmer and as an exercise I am trying to do some bots by using selenium.

I've built some bots by using 'webdriver.Chrome()' from Selenium. They were so slow that I was trying to speed them up by going headless mode or changing page_load_strategy etc.. In general, page loads take 9-10 secs.

I wanted to try 'webdriver.Safari()' to see if that is faster or not and I realized, it is insanely faster than Chrome. It is so fast that I need to slow it down, not only by using 'WebdriverWait' but the sleep method(which is not reliable on long period). On average page loads take 1-2 secs.

The reason this is a problem is for example:

```
def wait_page_load_by_css(self, css_selector: str, wait_time: int):
    print("Waiting for page to load... / ", end="")
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, wait_time).until(
        ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector)))
    print("Completed")


self.wait_page_load_by_css('example_css_selector', 30)
self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value = 'example_css_selector').click()
```

This code block may or may not work correctly because the last line of code will be executed before or after the javascript define the function for the corresponding button. Worst part is, program will not raise any error after 'click()' function executed cause it clicked, cause the element was present thanks to the previous line of code, but nothing happened.

Even with using 'sleep()', feels like my program is still not reliable, sometimes one error happen, sometimes not

Both browsers are updated to latest version, both ChromeDriver and SafariDriver downloaded. The Safaridriver is at /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin/safaridriver and Chromedriver is at /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

I am using macOS Sonoma 14.1.2

How one can built a cross platform bot using selenium without using sleep functions?
What is the reason for this speed difference between chrome and safari and what is the solution for this clicking before javascript runs problem?

Comment: Don't wait a specific time. Instead wait for the existence of specific element or variable or function to exist.

Comment: Isn't  this line of code exactly does that?
 self.wait_page_load_by_css('example_css_selector', 30)

Comment: You are waiting on the wrong thing. You said it yourself: `will be executed before or after the javascript define the function for the corresponding button`. Obviously waiting for the button to exist is not enough because it is breaking your code. You need to wait for the function to exist as well.

Comment: if the page load strategy is default, Selenium will wait for standard page loads to happen and always after a get().  WebDriverWaits are necessary after JS updates the DOM (instead of a standard page load).  This will take care of those cases and a sleep won't be necessary (it's a polling loop with 1/2 second sleeps inside of it).  It will only wait as long as necessary for the expected condition to occur or the timeout period is reached.  You should try/catch your driver calls.  Selenium throws very useful exceptions for dealing with situations where WebDriverWait is not enough.

Comment: for your .click() method you should use expected condition of elementToBeClickable: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.By)